# How to attach scroll bar into a div section?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've just wrote a page with couple div-s and little CSS and javascript. 
I don't know how to insert scroll bar into one of my div.
Code is not that hard to understand. CSS and javascript are included in code.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#container 
{
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 98%;
    height: 90%;
    padding: 5px;
}
#discussion {
    width: 99%;
    height: 90%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
    /*position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0;*/
    position: relative;
}
#content
{
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0;
}
#message {
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
</style>
<script>
function init(){
    var message = $('#message');
    var content = $('#content');
    message.keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13 && message.val().length > 0) {
            content.append(message.val() + "<br/>");
            //content.scrollTop(discussion.get(0).scrollHeight); //works fine with top to down
            message.val('').focus();
        }
    });
};
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="javascript:init();">
     <div id="container">
        <div id="discussion">
            <div id="content"></div>
        </div>
        <input id="message" type="text" placeholder="Hit Enter button to insert"/> 
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I need scroll bar when content gets out of discussion section.
Thing is when I insert some text with from top to bottom flow scroll bar works fine.
**Unfortunately, all text has to be inserted from bottom to top flow.**

```
---------------
-
-
-
-
- first text
---------------


---------------
-
-
-
- first text
- second text
---------------


---------------
- second text
- third text
- fourth text
- fifth text
- sixth text
--------------- now I need a scroll bar to see first text.
```

Comment: set height of the div then add overflow:auto it will works

Comment: `overflow:scroll` or if you want only vertical scroll bar use `overflow-y:scroll`

Comment: in which div you want scroll?

Comment: Content or discussion, any of them would be fine as long as I can scroll and see text inserted previously.

Comment: @ Mohsen that code fix shows scroll bar but that scroll bar doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You set the height to 90%, but it doesn't know what it's 90% of.
If you want it set to 90% of the body, you'll need to set `html,body {height: 100%;}`.

Then you need to remove the absolute positioning you put on the content.

Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/2PpqN/

Comment: In your working fiddle text is being inserted top to down flow. I need it to be inserted from bottom to top.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by inserting from bottom to top? Can you clarify further?

Comment: Added a picture to the question :P

Answer (score 0):

The main cause for the problem is you missed to set the width and height for **`#content`** div.

So add it

```
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

Also for the parent element **`discussion`**, instead of using % value stick to static values for `height` so that user can view it.  Currently it is very small to view the scroll.

```
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8v6S4/2/)

Hope you understand.

Comment: The reason I didn't include height in #content div is to show previously inserted text at bottom of div and next texts push previous content to top ... Sorry my bad English, I hope it makes sense.

Comment: @NarankhuuBoldbaatar The problem is you're not putting the text in `discussion` div, you're using `content` and that could be the actual prob causing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove overflow from `#discussion` and change postion to relative in `#content`

CSS

```
#discussion {
    width: 99%;
    height: 90%;

    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
    /*position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0;*/
    position: relative;
}
#content
{
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
}
```

updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/54zTQ/)